# Could all eigenvalues of this matrix be positive?

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, list-manipulation, eigenvalues

I have the following list $\beta$ with 5 equations

```
{
 (8 + n) λ[1]^2 + (4 (-1 + n) (1 + n)^4 λ[2]^2)/n^6 + λ[1] (-1 + (4 (-1 + n) (1 + n)^2 λ[2])/n^3) +m λ[5]^2,
 (λ[2] (-21 λ[2] - 33 n λ[2] - 3 n^2 λ[2] +n^3 (-1 + 12 λ[1] + 9 λ[2])))/n^3,
 (8 + m) λ[3]^2 + (4 (-1 + m) (1 + m)^4 λ[4]^2)/m^6 + λ[3] (-1 + (4 (-1 + m) (1 + m)^2 λ[4])/m^3) +n λ[5]^2,
 (λ[4] (-21 λ[4] - 33 m λ[4] - 3 m^2 λ[4] +m^3 (-1 + 12 λ[3] + 9 λ[4])))/m^3,
 λ[5] (-1 + (2 + n) λ[1] + (2 (-1 + n) (1 + n)^2 λ[2])/n^3 + 2 λ[3] + m λ[3] + (2 (-1 + m) (1 + m)^2 λ[4])/m^3 + 4 λ[5])
}
```

where `m`, `n` are integers as input.

Every time I assign some integer values to $m,n$ I can solve $\beta=0$ to get `λ[1], λ[2], λ[3], λ[4], λ[5]`.

With these ingredients, I can evaluate the eigenvalues of the matrix

```
Table[D[\beta[[i]], λ[j]], {i, 5}, {j, 5}] `
```

to check whether all eigenvalues are positive.

In summary, I want to know whether there exists some positive integers $m,n$ such that the eigenvalues of the matrix mentioned above are all positive.

Comment: hard to suggest specific solution since you did not show the function itself. But try [FindMaximum](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) or [MaxValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue.html) or [NMaxValue](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaxValue.html) there is also many questions here that ask to find max of function. You can search these.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for your comment. I tried to let this question be more specific. It would be very helpful if you can make further comment : )

Comment: @Vayne A couple of things: 1) setting your expression to zero gives you three equations and five unknowns (lambda 1 through 5); that's not enough to solve for them explicitly, isn't it? 2) The $\beta_{i}$ you showed does not depend on $i$, but on $n$. Should we understand $n$ to be $i$? 3) Please post expressions as MMA code, not $\LaTeX$, so we don't have to type them in ourselves. 4) Please come up with a better title for your question that describes the problem you are having. Summarizing one's problem in a few words sometimes helps clarify it for you as well, so it may be useful.

Comment: @MarcoB, thanks for the suggestions. I have made some modifications to the question. I will try to make more edits later when I can figure out a better way .

Comment: Did you mean `Table[D[\[Beta][[i]], \[Lambda][[j]], {i,5}, {j,5}]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, sorry for the bad notation. I will change \lambda1 to \[Lambda][[j]] in my question

Comment: I think the problem is well-posed, but the solution is taking very long.
For a specific case:
`tmp = Thread[\[Beta] == 0] /. {m -> 4, n -> 2}`
`sols = Solve[mymp, vars]` 
`mat = Grad[\[Beta] /. {m -> 4, n -> 2}, vars]` 
`Eigenvalues[mat] /. sols//N`
The Solve step for general {m,n} will give 30 solutions, all with conditions--so it will be messy (I didn't wait for the solution)

Comment: What is the matrix in question?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The matrix is Table[D[\beta[[i]], λ[j]], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]

Comment: @CraigCarter Thanks for the comment. I'm very confused about the existence of m,n such that all eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: This might be intractable.